# Redirect images in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two domains pointing to one application with different directories that is frontend on `www.frontend.com` and backend on `www.backend.com`. I have placed all images in the `frontend/uploads` folder, while on backend I cannot access the images on `frontend/uploads`.

How can I redirect all `^/uploads` to `www.frontend.com/uploads` using htaccess?

I have tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ http://frontend.com/uploads/$1
```

Comment: A redirect probably isn't the correct thing to do here, why can't you access these images from `backend.com`?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd just use a filesystem level symbolic link, as far more efficient (Unix, Linux, BSD, Darwin {OS X}) eg.

```
ln -s /srv/www/frontEnd/htdocs/uploads  /srv/www/backEnd/htdocs/uploads
```

and make sure you have the **FollowSymLinks** option set in the backend Directory block eg.

```
<Directory /srv/www/backEnd/htdocs/uploads>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

But assuming the **www.frontend.com** site is accessible to your **www.backend.com** users all you need in your backend config is:

```
RewriteRule ^/?uploads/.* http://frontend.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R=301]
```

If you take this approach I'd stick the rule in the **httpd.conf**, rather than a **.htaccess**, as that file is only parsed once on server startup, and the rule compiled, rather than having to parse the file for every request.